# The 2008 Istanbul UFO sighting: What does the video actually show?

Tags: ufo

[This](http://www.realufos.net/2008/10/ufo-over-istanbul-kumburgaz-turkey-not.html) UFO sighting had some decent-quality video, compared to what's typical for most other sightings. Strangely though, for a UFO sighting event with such good "evidence", there's been surprisingly little publicity or notability relating to it. What few news articles I could find mention the fact that it's supposedly been verified as being genuine footage. Here are my two questions:

1. Is the footage real or fake?
2. If it is real, what is the object shown in the video? The skeptic in me says it ain't aliens.

Comment: The document you linked gives a statement of authenticity. It attributes the statement to a Turkish academic group, but other pages attribute the statement to the founder of a UFO museum. For example: [this page](http://turkeyufocase.blogspot.com/). That casts serious doubt in my mind that this video has any special claim of legitimacy.

Comment: @MetaEd - Even if the video is 100% original footage that hasn't been manipulated good luck figuring out what that is without content to give you a sense of scale and other relevant information.

Comment: Is this link sufficient for an answer? http://forgetomori.com/2010/ufos/kumburgaz-turkey-ufo-yacht-window-reflections/

Comment: @Oddthinking - From what I read it looks like they did a pretty good job with it.

Comment: @Oddthinking - You have found a real jewel. This page was fun to read and demonstrated, once again, that we should not always believe our eyes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Andrés Duarte](http://usuarios.multimania.es/aduarte/) published an analysis in Spanish, which is non-peer-reviewed and self-published, but fairly systematic. It was translated to English by 
[Forgetomori](http://forgetomori.com/2010/ufos/kumburgaz-turkey-ufo-yacht-window-reflections/).

The sighting was not a single event, but a number of sightings spread out over two or three years.

The conclusion reached was that the images were

> mainly of yacht side windows reflecting light at night.

He determines the source and angle of the shots, and identifies the marina and the style of boat.

Comment: Impressive! Thank you, and senor Andres!

Comment: After watching the mentioned video I was fairly certain it's some sort of atmospheric optics phenomena playing tricks with the observers, some of it also due to camera optics. The cameraman says it's quite foggy outside, but since we see what appears to be a distant object relatively clearly, it was probably fairly humid but without visual condensation. All that combined can quite easily make distant object appear to be higher up the horizon than they really are, seemingly suspended mid air. Your answer confirms my suspicions. Cheers!